# Android Migrating from phone app to tablet

Tags: android, compatibility, tablet

I've developed an android phone app in which the navigation is mostly activities and starting activities for results. I've read that in order to make the tablet layout look like 2 screens of my phone app one next to the other I should have made it with fragments. Is there another way to migrate my functionality to the tablet app? Meaning to keep the start activity for result but just concatenate two activities on screen? (it may sound stupid, I know). Thanks

Comment: I think you will have to use fragment...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to keep the software design simple and modular, fragments come in really handy. You can use the same fragment's UI design + working code in multiple places without changing much functionality.

Since you have the code built and running in terms of activities, it won't take much time to migrate/port it to a Fragment since the life cycle methods are pretty similar. All you need to do is study the life cycle of a Fragment and move code chunks from the Activity to the Fragment class.

You can study all about Fragments here - http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html

or maybe a training session here will help you more - 
http://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/index.html

You will learn a lot and once you have tried it you will be able to comprehend the advantages in a much better way. In future always make it a point to design in terms of Fragments to have a much modular design.

Along with that I think you will also need to learn to design layout for multiple screen sizes. This link over here will help you understand how to support multiple screen sizes - 
http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html

If a tutorial to do this very quickly is what you seek then this should help -
http://www.101apps.co.za/index.php/articles/converting-android-activities-to-fragments.html

All the best :)

Answer (score 0):

It very depends on your app GUI structure. Sometimes, you even not need to adapt your GUI for tablet (if you build interface dynamically basing on screen dimension). As rule, if you have two screens where one screen is advanced or logical extension of other then you can union it into one screen on tablets for better informativeness. Secondary way, as rule, based on fragments.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve it with help of Activity group but it is deprecated in Api level 13, for more details please visit http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ActivityGroup.html, but I will suggest to go with Fragment as Fragment having nearly similar life cycle like as Activity with extra methods and features. Please refer link for more details http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html